# Perl: the value of variable $^T in child threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, variables, time, share

$^T stores the start time of a perl program in second since epoch.
Because I need to know how many seconds a child thread costs, the question is:
Does $^T in child thread store the beginning time of itself? or simply copy the value from its mother thread?

Comment: This sounds like something that would be trivial to test for yourself. Also - do you mean `thread` or `fork`. And - what are you trying to accomplish, because a measure of wallclock seconds is a crude metric at best.

Comment: Hi, I just tested it. It is indeed a copy of its mother. By the way, I use threads module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;


sub test_th {
    print $^T,"\n";
}

print $^T."\n"
sleep 10;
my $thr = threads -> create ( \&test_th ); 
$thr -> join;
```

Prints the same value twice.

Which is as expected, since when you thread, you effectively inherit all your parent variables.

If you try this via forking:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Parallel::ForkManager;

print $^T, "\n";

for ( 1 .. 2 ) {
    sleep 10;
    $mgr->start and next;
    print $^T, "\n";
    $mgr->finish;
}

$mgr->wait_all_children;
```

You get the same value, despite the 'start' of the fork being 10s later.

So to answer your question - no, `$^T` is started at program instantiation. If you wish to measure things like thread run times, you'll have to find other ways of doing it.

Although, given "elapsed time" is at best a very crude metric (processors doing things like scheduling, such that 'real time' and 'run time' don't really correlate particularly)

But perhaps calling `time()` at start and end of each thread would give you what you need? Or perhaps something like `Devel::NYTProf`?

Comment: And you'd probably want to use `Time::HiRes` if you're measuring elapsed time.

Comment: Yes, calling time() twice would be easy to understand. I will keep an eye on real and run time difference. Very thx.

Answer (score 0):

A quick test will reveal that `$^T` is defined for the populated at process startup, not at thread startup

But nothing's stopping you from noting when the thread starts. You can even save the time stamp in `$^T` since it's a per-thread variable!

```
use feature qw( say );
use threads;

sub thread {
   my ($n) = @_;
   sleep $n;
}

sub wrapper {
   my ($n) = @_;
   $^T = time;
   thread($n);
   say sprintf "Thread %s ran for %s seconds.", threads->tid, time-$^T;
}

async { wrapper(5) };
sleep 2;
async { wrapper(2) };
$_->join for threads->list;
```

Output:

```
Thread 2 ran for 2 seconds.
Thread 1 ran for 5 seconds.
```

Note that assigning to `$^T` coerces the stored value into an integer, so it would not be an appropriate place to store the result of `Time::HiRes::time()`.